# Get buttons foreground color

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8.1, brush

Tried many combinations such as:

```
        SolidColorBrush b = (SolidColorBrush)myButton.Foreground;
        b.Color.ToString();
```

It returns:
Windows.Ui.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush

But I need to know the color, ex: White.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create extension method and get color name from `Colors` class:

```
public static class ColorEx
{
    public static string GetColorName(this SolidColorBrush scb)
    {
        string result = null;
        foreach (var pi in typeof(Colors).GetRuntimeProperties())
        {
            Color c = (Color)pi.GetValue(null);
            if (c == scb.Color)
            {
                result = pi.Name;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In the `ColorEx` class you can use LINQ to make code more readable and much shorter:

```
public static class ColorEx
{
    public static string GetColorName(this SolidColorBrush scb)
    {
        return typeof(Colors).GetRuntimeProperties().Where(x => (Color)x.GetValue(null) == scb.Color).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Example:

```
SolidColorBrush b = (SolidColorBrush)myButton.Foreground;
Debug.WriteLine(b.GetColorName());
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do it:

```
        SolidColorBrush s = btn.Foreground as SolidColorBrush;
        string name="";
        foreach (KnownColor kc in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
        {
            System.Drawing.Color known = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(kc);
            if (System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(s.Color.A, s.Color.R, s.Color.G, s.Color.B).ToArgb() == known.ToArgb())
            {
                name = known.Name;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(name);
```

the `s.Color` object is a `System.Windows.Media.Color`, so I am 'converting' it to `System.Drawing.Color` in order to find it's name using the `KnownColor` enum.